# Which languages do not have Global Vars?

Tags: programming-languages, global-variables

Due to a wave of criticism to use Global Vars in [my Java post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607158/java-how-to-have-global-values-inside-a-class), I want to use a language without global vars. One suggestion per answer, thank you.

Comment: By convention poll-type questions, if appropriate, should be community wiki.

Comment: The day you find one, let us know :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want global variables then don't use them. I'm don't see why finding a language that doesn't support them would offer any value.  You're dealing with a question of scope. Make your variables exist in the lowest scope possible and you'll be fine.  There is no language that doesn't have a global scope.

Comment: I disagree. By including global variables in a language, you are allowing all 3rd-party libraries to access the disk, do HTTP requests, etc. Want to parse an XML string? Then you'd better make sure you trust the author. OS user permissions may not be fine-grained enough to prevent this.

I don't know any languages like that (which is why I'm here). But it's certainly possible to provide the globals in an argument to the main function, instead of as globals per se.

I don't care about all globals - I'd be happy for pure functions (text processing, trig functions, etc) to remain as globals.

Comment: "If you don't want global variables then don't use them." .... as if it's that easy. If you link against a library with a global variable, now you cannot reason about your own code without taking into account that global.

Comment: It's hard to disagree with either of these comments since we aren't talking about a certain language, but since we're talking in theory you could just build a wrapper around a 3rd party library. And that is even assuming a third party library is something you can load in the language. The same applies for accessing the disk. Not all languages can do this. The language might be running in a runtime that doesn't allow code to access the disk. There are many scripting languages that are very limited. But every language has global scope, and you should avoid having variables in the global scope.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you literally mean no global *variables* (values that change), or if you also want to rule out global *constants* (values that don't change). Haskell is one such language that doesn't have global variables, although it does have global constants (in the form of parameterless functions, essentially). In Haskell, if you want to emulate global state, you have to pass your "global" variables into each function you call. A better description is available from the [HaskellWiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Global_variables).

Comment: Does standard Haskell even have "variables" (not counting mutable values faked by monads)?

Comment: It depends on how you define a variable. The variables in Haskell are best described as constants in imperative languages. In Haskell the value assigned to a variable can never be changed. See also http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Variable

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid side-effects you can use one of the pure functional programming languages like haskell (or erlang or ...), which have only constants. But be prepared for a completely different kind of programming compared to the imperative programming style.

Answer (score 1):

Java (and similar OOP-languages) doesn't have really global variables, all variables are tied to an instance or a class. But I think you want also outrule the 'simulated' global variables (public fields with the only reason to be accessed from the outside). I don't think any of the popular languages don't allow this, but more uncommon language-concepts may have ways to avoid such things.

Answer (score 1):

Newspeak has no global namespace and so no global variables, everything is late bound, I think other langages in the BETA family have the same property.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak_(programming_language)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I read that Graal is a functional programming language without variables, so I guess that might qualify.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Eiffel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_%28programming_language%29)  doesn't use global variables but that isn't a serious criterion
of whether to use a language or not.

Answer (score 0):

The latest one entering this club would be V.